# Laravel error on view with render (or links) method, combining 2 queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have this 2 queries

```
$a = Message::where('conversation_id',$id)->where('user_id',$user->id)->where('s_1',1)
        ->get();
    $b = Message::where('user_id',$conversation->recipients()->last()->user->id)->where('s_1',1)
        ->get();

    $result = $a->merge($b);
    $messages = $result;
```

all well i pass the var messages to the view, but in the view the method render or links dont work to paginate the results:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            @foreach($messages as $i => $message)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="{{$avatar[$message->user->username]}}" class="aoi pull-left"  />
                    <a href="{{route('profile',[$message->user->username])}}">{{ $message->user->name }}</a> 
                    - <script>
                    moment.locale("es");
                    document.writeln(moment.utc("{{ $message->created_at }}", "YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss").fromNow());
                    </script>
                    <br>
                    {{ $message->body }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
        {!! str_replace('/?', '?', $messages->render()) !!}
```

Comment: why do you have that str replace there?

Comment: Add `paginate()` in query

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the paginate() function for getting your record.

you should try this.

```
$b = Message::where('user_id',$conversation->recipients()->last()->user->id)->where('s_1',1)
        ->orderBy('user_id','desc')->paginate(10);
```

this will automatically get() the record matching to your query, and 
you only have to do for the pagination like ,

```
{{$b->appends(request()->input())->links()}}
```

this will automatically give the links to next pages if record will be more then your paginate limit (10) .

Comment: `{{ $b->appends(\Request::except('page'))->render() }}` I use that approach (just 2 cents)